# is it possible to show the pod pause image address in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I want to check the pod pause image address, then using this command to check:

```
> kubectl get pod reddwarf-postgresql-postgresql-0 -o=jsonpath='{.spec.containers[0].image}' -n reddwarf-storage

registry.cn-hongkong.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/postgresql:v1.0.1%
```

this shows the pod main containers image address, what should I do to show the pod pause image address?